# Is my connection speed okay?

Tags: networking, speed, isp, adsl2+

I have a so-called ADSL2+ connection with this characteristics displaying in my zyxel modem page:

noise margin downstream: 9.6 dB

output power upstream: 12.2 dbm

attenuation downstream: 34.2 dB

Upon checking in google, regarding the relationship between attenuation and speed (Mb/s), I found out I can get more than 10 Mb/s with the reported figures whereas I'm getting 4 Mb/s at maximum. The ISP says my neighborhood has old communication facility with some attachment between wires en route, and there's no chance to receive more bitrate.

So my question: if the problem is the old facility, shouldn't it affect the attenuation number in the first place?

Comment: "with some attachment between wires en route," there is probably also poor wiring between you and the ISP DSLAM

Comment: In a nutshell, they're probably right but they should do something about it anyway. Depending on your jurisdiction a minimal service level - typically 90% of the speed 90% of the time - may apply.

Comment: It always helps if you tell us which country you are in. If it's UK, then there are one or two isp's who will take a big stick to BT. One thing that can harm the connection is if any part of it is alluminium, yes, BT did not always use copper everywhere.